# Why two or more spaces becomes one space in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a simple HTML/JS/Angular script to demonstarte the problem I have faced. I have a work-around, but still wanted to post this question to the experts.

```
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller='abc'>
         <h1 ng-click='title= "A     B     C    D        EFGH";'>{{title}}   </h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Angualr Code:

```
function abc($scope) {
   $scope.title = 'Hello World';
};
```

When Clciked on :
continuous spaces in-side the string are replaced with single space.
Output is "A B C D EFGH"

Why is this happening?

Comment: Yes, that's how HTML works. A million spaces is one space. You may want to use a space entity `&nbsp;`

Comment: use `&nbsp;` instead of literal spaces as browsers converts them to one space without using `<pre>` html tag

Answer (score 2):

Collapsing spaces is just another browser's default behavior that you can change using a CSS property, and in this case it is `white-space`.

[white-space CSS property on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

As an example, this will preserve the amount of spaces you entered.

```
h1 {
    white-space: pre;
}
```